# OneSignal Background Data Notification

Tags: javascript, react-native, push-notification, onesignal

I'm trying to send a Background Data Notification via `OneSignal` in a React Native App. This is possible through the `OneSignal` dashboard, and I can achieve my desired effect - no sound and no banner displayed on the device on Android.

[image]

I am now trying to replicate this both via the `REST API` and `react-native-onesignal` SDK but can't get this to work as it seems they both require the `"en"` language field to be entered - which results in a notification sound and banner displayed on the device.

Via the SDK and via REST.

```
OneSignal.postNotification({'en':' '},{'data':'yo'},
                'XXXXXX-XXXX-XXX-b45c-XXXXXXX',{'en':''})
```

Results in an error

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: {"errors":["Message Notifications must have English language content"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your POST:

```
"android_background_data" : true
```